# Simple Regex Befuddlement

Tags: c#, regex

I have some strings of the form

```
string strA = "Cmd:param1:'C:\\SomePath\SomeFileName.ext':param2";
string strB = "Cmd:'C:\\SomePath\SomeFileName.ext':param2:param3";
```

I want to split this string on ':' so I can extract the N parameters. Some parameters can contain file paths [as explicitly] shown and I don't want to split on the ':'s that are within the parentheses. I can do this with a regex but I am confused as to how to get the regex to split only if there is no "'" on both sides of the colon.

I have attempted

```
string regex = @"(?<!'):(?!')"; 
string regex = @"(?<!'(?=')):";
```

that is continue matching only if no "'" on the left and no "'" on the right (negative look behind/ahead), but this is still splitting on the colon contained in 'C:\SomePath\SomeFileName.ext'.

**How can I amend this regex to do as I require?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Note: I have found that **the following regex works**. However, **I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this?***

```
string regex = @"(?<!.*'.*):|:(?!.*'.*)";
```

Comment: Using single quotes to delimit Windows paths is not as, well, smart as using double quotes; single quotes are legal characters in paths while double quotes are not, so using double quotes (even if they have to be escaped) would make it a lot easier to parse.

Comment: @JAB you are definitely right, but as with most things, this is a relic that I am left to deal with from a design decision made many moons ago...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this approach:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var r = Regex.Replace(strA, @"'.*'", m =>
{
    return m.Value.Replace(":", guid);
})
.Split(':')
.Select(s => s.Replace(guid, ":"))
.ToList();
```

Comment: I like this a lot. I have not used or even come across the `Guid` class. Top top work and thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to construct a lookbehind regex to split on, you could construct a regex to match the fields themselves and take the set of matches of that regex. EG a field is either a quoted sequence of non-quotes (ie can include `:`), or it can't include the separator:

```
string regex = "'[^']*'|[^':]*";
var result = Regex.Matches(strA, regex);
```

Comment: You don't need the first `[^']`, non-greedy matching works fine too. `"'.*?'|[^':]*`. (Leaving aside the possibility of the paths having single quotes in them, of course, but as it's apparently a preexisting design decision the system Killercam is working with hopefully disallows that.)

Comment: @Killercam It should match your parameters and not the colons. He's matching, not splitting.

Comment: I am aware of the Matching, but this will also return blank spaces - it needs some attention and is not a solution as it in its current form as it requires 'post-processing'...

Answer (score 1):

You want to split on `(?<!\b[a-z]):(?!\\)` (use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`).

Answer (score 1):

Not as pretty but you could replace `:\` with safe characters and then return them back to `:\` after the split.

```
string[] param = strA.Replace(@":\", "|||").Split(':').Select(x => x.Replace("|||", @":\")).ToArray();
```